# What is the simplest way to consume an external REST service in Lagom?

Tags: java, lagom

According to Lagom documentation, we can define external service URI (like below) and can get it from ServiceLocator.

`lagomUnmanagedServices in ThisBuild := Map("weather" -> "http://localhost:3333")`

http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.0.x/ServiceLocator.html#Communicating-with-external-services

What is the simplest way to call the external REST API in Lagom?

I considered using WsClient in Lagom, but I didn't choose it.
Lagom includes only WsClient for Scala, therefore it provides result values as not `java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage` but `scala.concurrent.Future`.
It makes the pain to combine with other Lagom APIs like [CompletionStage#doWithService](http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.0.x/api/java/com/lightbend/lagom/javadsl/api/ServiceLocator.html#doWithService-java.lang.String-com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.api.Descriptor.Call-java.util.function.Function-).

Comment: That's a really good question. +1

Comment: Here's a sample java project (not a lagom project) that uses Lagom's libraries (not the the whole framework) to consume third party API's: https://github.com/ignasi35/lagom-client-demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to consume 3rd party REST services from lagom is by writing the 3rd party's REST spec using a Lagom `Descriptor`.

Imagine your code wanted to interact with Slack's API, you would create a `slack-api` project in your app and create the [Slack descriptor](https://gist.github.com/ignasi35/9351ef4bdc5f7768e27182d06bfc8c01) there (you wouldn't need to create a `slack-impl`of course).

Then, on your `fancy-impl` code you would depend on `slack-api` and in your `FancyServiceImpl` implementation you would inject `SlackService` in the constructor.

PS: The gist is scala code, but same idea applies to Lagom's Java DSL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

As none of the previous answers contain full information on how to implement it in Java, here's how I did it:

1. Create Lagom API module, e.g. external-service-api and put request/response DTOs and Lagom service in it, e.g.:

   ```
   public interface ExternalService extends Service {

       ServiceCall<ExternalServiceRequest, ExternalServicePostResponse> somePostMethod();

       ServiceCall<NotUsed, ExternalServiceGetResponse> someGetMethod();

       @Override
       default Descriptor descriptor(){
           return Service.named("external-service").withCalls(
               Service.pathCall("/post-endpoint", this::somePostMethod),
               Service.pathCall("/get-endpoint", this::someGetMethod)
           ).withAutoAcl(true);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add dependency to your external-service-api in impl module where you want to use it.
3. Register your service in *Module.java. Use: `bindClient(ExternalService.class);`
4. Now the tricky part, I found some tutorials/repositories in which unmanaged service was defined in pom.xml in implementation module. It didn't work for me, and I don't know why (Lagom v. 1.4.5, Scala binaries 2.12). What I had to do, was to put unmanagedServices definitions in projects root pom.xml. Take notice that unmanagedService child element should be named same as you defined in descriptor.

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>com.lightbend.lagom</groupId>
           <artifactId>lagom-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>${lagom.version}</version>
           <configuration>
               <unmanagedServices>
                   <external-service>http://api.url.com/</external-service>
               </unmanagedServices>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   ```
5. Inject your service:

   ```
   @Inject
   public SomeConstructor(ExternalService externalService){
       ...
   }
   ```
6. To use it call e.g.: `externalService.somePostMethod().invoke(new ExternalServiceRequest(...))`

Answer (score 0):

In Lagom, any 3rd party application/service can be accessed as an unmanaged service. You would need to add that in your application.conf like this

`#external-services
lagom.services {
  3rd-party-service-identifier = "http://3rd-party-service-url"
  ...
}`
 
and would also need to add the 3rd party service url as an unmanagedService in the pom.xml like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.lightbend.lagom</groupId>
    <artifactId>lagom-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${lagom.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <kafkaEnabled>false</kafkaEnabled>
      <cassandraEnabled>false</cassandraEnabled>
      <unmanagedServices>
        <3rd-party-service-identifier>${3rd-party-service-URL}</3rd-party-service-identifier>
      </unmanagedServices>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

this is how you let Lagom know about the 3rd party service, but to make lagom to work with the service please go to the link below.
https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/java/IntegratingNonLagom.html